# Angular6 create folder like node_module

Tags: angular, angular6, lib

I'm trying to create a folder in my project where I could put a set of custom lib of Angular 6 and being able to import them as I do with libs inside `node_module` folders.

```
import { SampleLibModule } from 'SambleLib';
```

I assume I have to declare my folder in the `tsconfig.json` file but I tried few things and it didn't worked

Comment: I am not sure but I guess you are asking how to include the module in any other component file so for this you have to create the module as per your need and add this module in app.module.ts. Then you can import module and access the components related to it.

Answer (score 0):

From Angular 6, using angular cli you can now generate libraries within your project.

From an angular project directory `ng generate library mylib --prefix aa` will create a new library with the name "mylib" and components will be prefixed "aa" instead of app (or whatever your main project uses).

Here is the wiki for the command : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-library

You will need to build your library with `ng build mylib`

Here is a blog post explaining further how to do this:
https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11